# Okhttp doesn't return cached response when using Etags

Tags: android, okhttp, etag, if-none-match

I have a simple use case where a server returns an **Etag** for a request and that etag is added as a header (i.e. `If-None-Match`) to all subsequent url requests. The server can respond with a `200` if there is a change in the response or a `304` otherwise. For the latter, it makes sense to reuse the response from cache. But okhttp always returns `null` as the cached response.

I did some troubleshooting and the response is written to disk internally by okhttp but the `CachingStrategy` doesn't return it to the `CacheInterceptor`. Looking closely into the `CachingStrategy` class, there is [documentation specifically](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/internal/cache/CacheStrategy.kt#L280) stating that the cache won't be used:

```
 /**
     * Returns true if the request contains conditions that save the server from sending a response
     * that the client has locally. When a request is enqueued with its own conditions, the built-in
     * response cache won't be used.
     */
    private fun hasConditions(request: Request): Boolean =
        request.header("If-Modified-Since") != null || request.header("If-None-Match") != null
  }
```

Is there a way to workaround this behavior and use the cached response instead?

(I have caching enabled as described [here](https://square.github.io/okhttp/recipes/#response-caching) and I am using okhttp version `3.10.0`)

<s>*Also, strangely I am having to manually add the Etag. Okhttp fails to add the etag to subsequent requests on its own.*</s>

**Edit** - correction, Okhttp correctly adds the etag header. I needed to use a network interceptor vs a regular one to see the etag header being added to the subsequent requests

Somewhat related to these issues:

- https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1400
- https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/831#issuecomment-57900979

Comment: did you try this using postman

Comment: postman wouldn't help much in this case because it's going to be give me a `304` response alright but the problem here is with okhttp where it doesn't return the cached response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you do your own caching, or you let OkHttp’s cache do the caching. When you add your own conditions, OkHttp assumes you want full control of the caching and it does not participate in that.

Comment: got it, makes sense. If I let OkHttp handle the etags (assuming it works well. I wasn't able to get it to work oddly and so had to add the header manually), would it let Okhttp perform its normal caching and return the cache response?

Comment: after digging into this further I realized that I made a rookie mistake of adding the logging interceptor to the interceptors list instead of the networkInterceptors. Okhttp is in fact adding the etag header correctly

Comment: the solution here was to just let okhttp manage the etags and the cache is correctly returned as the response